# How can I make my URL and BreadCrumb reflect my menu structure in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have this structure on my WordPress site for the menu hierocracy:

> 1. Home
> 2. Services
>
>    2a) Web D&D (Web Design & Development)

```
         2aa) Custom Software Development
         2ab) Content Management Platforms
```

> ```
> 3b) Web Tutoring Services
> ```

Services is not a page.  I just need that on the top level menu to hold "Web D&D" and "Web Tutoring Services".

I started off with Services as a category and the menu structure looks right but the URL and BreadCrumb (in the Sinatra theme) do not reflect the complete menu pathway which is what I want.  It just always says "Home -> PostName".  I understand this is how I have it defined in PermaLinks.  But how can I define it to reflect the actual whole Menu Pathway.
I have All-In-One installed but I have not activated it.
So I do not have any SEO yet.

Here is a pic of one example:

[image]

So you can see I've navigated to "Home -> Services -> Custom Software".
But the URL and BreadCrumb both say "Home -> Software".

Also I did not really need Services as a Category.  When I clicked on it was going to a posts page for the category Services. So I removed that and replaced it with a custom link menu item that just goes to "#" or nowhere.  I I wish WordPress had like a group menu item just to group child items but did not navigate anywhere.

At any rate, is there a way to make the breadcrumb and URL reflect the actual menu structure?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You have to go to the Page Settings tab in the Settings (gear icon in the upper right).  Look for Page Attributes and under there you can set the page parent.  Then your breadcrumbs and URL will reflect the true structure of your URL.  I still can't get the Services Grouping item (my custom link menu item) to show in their.  I guess I'll have to make a services page and figure out the content for it.  I guess it will be like a sitemap page to the services section.